# Add array in ListView and replace number by Image

Tags: android, arrays, listview, replace

I have two arrays:

```
int[] sinais = new int[arraySinais.length];
String[] arraySSID = new String[] { };
```

And I joined them into one array:

```
String[] arrayScan = new String[arraySinais.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arraySSID.length; i++) {
    arrayScan[i] = arraySSID[i] + " " + sinais[i];
}
```

But now I need to add this new array in a `ListView` and replace `int` numbers by an `ImageView`. 
Example:

```
for (int i = 1; i < Sinais.length; i++) {
                    if (Sinais[i] <= 25){
                        //ImageView01
                        ArrayImagens[i] = R.drawable.image01;
                    } else if ((Sinais[i] > 25) && (Sinais[i] <= 50)) {
                        //ImageView02
                        ArrayImagens[i] = R.drawable.image02;
                    } else if ((Sinais[i] > 50) && (Sinais[i] <= 75)) {
                        //ImageView03
                        ArrayImagens[i] = R.drawable.image03;
                    } else if ((Sinais[i] > 75) && (Sinais[i] <= 100)) {
                        //ImageView04
                        ArrayImagens[i] = R.drawable.image04;
                    } 
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declare `arrayImagens` as image array which is `Image[]`.

```
Image[] arrayImagens = new Image[13];


for (int i = 1; i < Sinais.length; i++) {
    if (Sinais[i] <= 25){
        //ImageView01
        arrayImagens [i] = R.drawable.image01;
    } else if ((Sinais[i] > 25) && (Sinais[i] <= 50)) {
        //ImageView02
        arrayImagens [i] = R.drawable.image02;
    } else if ((Sinais[i] > 50) && (Sinais[i] <= 75)) {
        //ImageView03
        arrayImagens [i] = R.drawable.image03;
    } else if ((Sinais[i] > 75) && (Sinais[i] <= 100)) {
        //ImageView04
        arrayImagens [i] = R.drawable.image04;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hope it helps, feel free to ask me if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I've created a CustomListViewAdapter:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                                 List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And other xml for the `ListView` row.